# GREP on MACOS 10.6 for '<?' but not '<?php'

Tags: regex, grep, osx-snow-leopard

Hi I am trying to ensure that none of the files have

```
<?
```

(PHP short tag) and they do have

```
<?PHP
```

So far I have got to

```
grep -r -E '<?*' * | grep -Ev '<?php' >> /phptags.txt
```

so this should give me a blank file called phptags.txt in my root folder if all the

I have tried using the escape character for the ? ie. /? following the advice on the URL below

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10004/what-does-mean-in-a-regular-expression

previous experience how shown that on MacOS10.6 the grep regex doesn't need the ? to be escaped to search for it as a literal string...but it's not working!

any advice people? Thanks in advance

James

Comment: Should work the way you have it if you just remove the `*` and `-E` and just `grep -r '<?'` then pipe to the inverse

Comment: And add `-i` to the second grep.

Comment: if you're planning on doing a global replace, you should watch out for XML files that begin with `<?xml`

Comment: thanks [code]grep -r '<?' * | grep -iv '<?php' >> /phptags.txt[/code] works great.

Comment: @JamesCat I'll add as an answer below then.

Answer (score 1):

Without the `-E` flag and the `*` wildcard, your `'<?'` pattern will match and work as intended, after which you can pipe to the inverse.  It is recommended to add the `-i` case-insensitive flag as well:

```
grep -ir '<?' * | grep -iv '<?php' >> /phptags.txt
```

Otherwise, in your attempt, what happens is this:  `<?*` as an extended regular expression matches first `<`, which `?` makes optional, followed by `*` which means "zero or more of the preceding expression". So in effect, this matches anything that does or does not begin with `<?`, therefore matching everything.

If you switch to the basic mode (not `-E`), the `<?` are matched literally. Pipe that to the inverse `-v` `<?php` which is also matched literally to remove those.